# C# How to run delayed method in between timer ticks

Tags: c#, timer, delay

I am using a timer to run a method every 16 minutes. I also want to run a second method every minute for 15 minutes in-between.

Below is the code I am using:

```
int count =  0;

private void cmdGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        t.Interval = 960000; // specify interval time - 16 mins
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        t.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RunMethod1();

        while(count < 15)
        {
            //waiting for 60 seconds 
            DateTime wait = DateTime.Now;
            do
            {
                 Application.DoEvents();
            } while (wait.AddSeconds(60) > DateTime.Now);

            RunMethod2();
        }
}
```

The above code seems to work fine but the ‘do while’ loop to wait for 60 seconds is very CPU heavy.

I tried to use Thread.Sleep(60000) but this freezes up the Interface and also tried to add a second timer within timer_Tick but this doesn’t seem possible. Can a second timer be added within the EventHandler of the first?

Is there any other method to achieve this without being so CPU intensive?

Thanks!
Warren

NOTE: Sorry guys, there was a typo in my original post. The 60 second wait do, while loop should have been within the while < 15 loop. Just updated the code snippet.

So:

- RunMethod1() should be executed every 16 mins
- RunMethod2() should be executed every 1 min (15 times) in between the 16 min tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to have a counter to store how many times the clock has gone off. Then set your timer interval to fire once a minute so not doing anything in between...

That way you could just do...

```
private int Counter;

private void cmdGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 60000; // specify interval time - 1 minute
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    t.Start();
}

// Every 1 min this timer fires...
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If it has been 16 minutes then run RunMethod1
    if (++Counter >= 16)
    {
        Counter = 0;
        RunMethod1();         
        return;
    }

    // Not yet been 16 minutes so just run RunMethod2
    RunMethod2();
}
```

Comment: Your code and OP's code are semantically different. OP's code calls `RunMethod1` after 16 minutes but yours will call it in 1 minute

Comment: The OP question was how to run Method1 every minute and Method2 every 16 minutes... This is how you can achieve that?

Comment: If that's what being asked, you're rite. I was confused to see *The above code seems to work fine*. It is not clear what OP wants :( If this is what he wants his code shouldn't work isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my original post :( Have updated it now, please see above

Comment: @user3584576 - I have changed code slightly. You can see that `RunMethod2` will run every minute for 15 minutes and on the 16th minute then `RunMethod1` will execute and so on. This is clean, easy to read and doesn't mess about with `Thread.Sleep` etc.

Comment: Hi Belogix, thanks for the suggestion! I need RunMethod1() to be executed before RunMethod2() but I can do that within the cmdGo_Click EventHandler before starting the timer. This looks good. Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could `await` a task Delay so the UI will keep responding

```
    async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunMethod1();



        while (count < 15)
        {
            //waiting for 60 seconds 
            await Task.Delay(60000);

            RunMethod2();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you aware of `Task.Delay` ? `Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(60000))` unnecessarily wasting 1 thread for 1 minute.

Comment: This would run `RunMethod2` 15 times in quick succession rather than one minute between each one.

Comment: @Belogix Agreed, only replied to the piece of offending code of the OP's original code. Altered the wait location to the new location. However, I also didn't go into the underlying question. Taking that into account, the OP is better off with an alternative method such as in your post.

Comment: This code will run less than once/minute. The time RunMethod1/2 take to execute will be added on every minute, meaning you'll drift, possibly by a significant amount, depending on what you're doing / how long your app has been running.